# Azure WebJobs: Error loading part

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have an azure webjob that was deployed few days ago and it seems that it was working normally. Since this morning, if I'm trying to access the azure webjob through the new portal, I'm getting a strange error message: Error loading part...

Does someone knows how this can be "debugged"?

Thank you
Evdin

Comment: I, too, am getting the same. I note that as I already had a deployment set up that the deployment is still being triggered on my Github check-in, I just can't see any of the deployments and their respective statuses or make changes to the trigger. I get that this is a 'preview portal', but there are things that you simply cannot do in the old management portal.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the Azure users are facing this issue due to migration from Old portal to New portal. As the new portal is still in *preview* it's better to use old portal if you face any issue in new portal.Also, raise a support ticket to inform microsoft so that they can work on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have been experiencing numerous problems with the Azure portal today. First and foremost continous deployment stopped working so, I've been unable to update my web apps.

But I'm also getting: "Error loading part..." in several other areas. I can only recommend creating some buzz, so Azure is alerted to the issues.

Answer (score 1):

If you see these type of errors in IE you can press F12 to see the errors.
Chrome/Firefox can also show HTTP message details.

I am also seeing errors in the new portal.
I was trying to see azure website and I saw "error loading part" errors.

Microsoft_Azure_Billing]  ‎9‎:‎30‎:‎19‎ ‎AM MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter 2 message: Access is denied.

[WebsitesExtension]  ‎9‎:‎30‎:‎19‎ ‎AM MsPortalFx.Base.Diagnostics.ErrorReporter 2 message: Access is denied.

New portal is in preview but is no longer optional as many of the services are only available in the new portal. Azure support should be informed to make them aware of this issue.

Comment: Where can I inform Microsoft regarding these issues because it seems that I need to have a support contract to be able to raise a ticket. Thank you.

Comment: You are correct that you need a support contact to information MSFT. I purchased a developer support plan for $29 a month. It is an awesome deail. One support case will pay for a years worth of charges.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue is now fixed but I see another strange issue now - the webjob that I described above is showing as "running on demand" in the new portal (I didn't set it up like this) and is showing as "running every six hours" in the old portal (this is how I set it up)... So it seems that everything is screwed overthere...

Thank you for your responses and your help.
Evdin